# How can I create a partial duplication of another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of Ids and dates.

```
id  date
1   2010-03-09 00:00:00
1   2010-05-28 00:00:00
1   2010-10-12 00:00:00
1   2010-12-10 00:00:00
1   2011-07-11 00:00:00
```

I'd like to reshape the dataframe so that I have one date in one column, and the next date adjacent in another column.  See below

```
id  date                 date2
1   2010-03-09 00:00:00  2010-05-28 00:00:00
1   2010-05-28 00:00:00  2010-10-12 00:00:00
1   2010-10-12 00:00:00  2010-12-10 00:00:00
1   2010-12-10 00:00:00  2011-07-11 00:00:00
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['date2'] = df.date.shift(-1)        # use shift function to shift index of the date 
                                       # column and assign it back to df as a new column

df.dropna()                            # the last row will be nan for date2, drop it if you 
                                       # don't need it
#  id                  date               date2
#0  1   2010-03-09 00:00:00 2010-05-28 00:00:00
#1  1   2010-05-28 00:00:00 2010-10-12 00:00:00
#2  1   2010-10-12 00:00:00 2010-12-10 00:00:00
#3  1   2010-12-10 00:00:00 2011-07-11 00:00:00
```

Comment: Oh, that is classy

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Psidom has a swaggy answer already ... but since I was already at it:

```
df_new = df.iloc[:-1]
df_new['date2'] = df.date.values[1:]
```

Comment: Mmm, yea that is what I cooked up too on my own as well.